# Servlet Exception

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

I am getting this error while running my servlet program .Can anyone let me know why I m getting this error

```
        java.lang.ClassCastException:org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher cannot be cast to org.apache.catalina.servlet4preview.RequestDispatcher
        net.codejava.HelloServlet.doGet(HelloServlet.java:35)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
```

Comment: Hmm... it might be related to your code.

Comment: Include some of your code if you use maven or gradle post your dependencies otherwise we don't know how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

> This can happen when you have Tomcat-specific JAR files in your
>   webapp's /WEB-INF/lib. This is not right. You should remove all
>   servletcontainer-specific JAR files from there. They do not belong
>   there at all. They are supposed to be already provided by the
>   servletcontainer itself. The /WEB-INF/lib should only contain
>   libraries specific to the webapp itself which are not provided by the
>   servletcontainer.